# What does "High Availability" on Uffizzi Cloud's Enterprise Tier mean?

Tags: deployment, hosting, devops

So as I'm trying to decide how to use Uffizzi cloud and looking at different tiers, I see that the Enterprise tier has "High Availability". I'm not sure exactly what this means. Does this mean the other tiers aren't always available? I didn't think I would need enterprise necessarily but I do need my application to available at all times. Anybody know exactly what the phrase means?

Answer (score 0):

**High availability** normally refers your **server** being **reachable most of the time**. A time interval a server not being reachable is also called **downtime**.

Downtime can happen for various reasons like maintenance of the system, power shortage, network issues, etc... High availability is a term for making sure, the **downtime** of your **server** is at a **minimum**.

Answer (score 0):

High Availability (HA) on uffizzi means your app will be deployed and load-balanced across three different datacenters aka Availability Zones (AZs). This is a DevOps best practice to significantly reduce the amount of down time for your application.  If there was a hardware, networking or any other failure in one AZ your app would still be able to service your users because it is actively running in 3 AZs - not just the one that may have had a failure.  HA will cost more and it's ultimately a business decision of do you want to pay a little more for reliability -  what does an outage cost you in terms of reputation, lost revenue or other negative impacts.